# Raspivid save to disk and stream concurrently

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to run a home security camera using Rasberry Pi Model B

I want to save the stream to a file locally (USB if possible) and also stream so I can pick this up on my network

The command I have is not working for both - any suggestions?

```
raspivid-o security.h264 -t 0 -n -w 600 -h 400 -fps 12 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -n -w 600 -h 400 -fps 12 | tee security.h264 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264
```

The tee command writes the output to the standard output and to the specified files.